# Terraform cannot authenticate to Snowflake using privatelink host

Tags: azure, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I set up Snowflake with **Azure Private Link** using Terraform, the goal was to **activate a network policy** to only enable connection coming from the private network. This means the Snowflake would be accessible with the following host (after the Azure DNS configuration is achieved) `***.***.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com`.

But logically, **Terraform can not activate the policy** since it is using the public Snowflake host. For the same reason, if you activate the policy manually Terraform won't be able to perform any actions in the future. So I separated my Terraform code into two "layers" with distinct states: one for the Azure-related resources and the other one for the Snowflake provider. There is an implicit dependence between the two. Indeed the Azure Private Endpoints and DNS config must be deployed beforehand so I can use the privatelink host for the Snowflake provider, which I believe would solve my problem.

### TLDR; I tried this

```
provider "snowflake" {
  account  = "${var.SNOWFLAKE_ORG}-${var.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT}" # the Snowflake account identifier
  username = var.SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME                          # the Snowflake user name
  # Password defined with env variable SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD
  role = "ACCOUNTADMIN"
  host = "app-${var.SNOWFLAKE_ORG}-${var.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT}.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com"
}
```

And I get his:

```
Error: could not retrieve session id err = 261004 (08004): failed to auth for unknown reason. HTTP: 405
```

### More infos

- I am able to authenticate to the UI using a VM that is inside the virtual network.
- I tried different hosts:

`<locator>.<region>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com`

`<org>-<account>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com`

`app-<org>-<account>.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com`

- The `nslookup` does resolve the IP
- Related issue I opened in GitHub: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/terraform-provider-snowflake/issues/1905

**Is it even possible to use the privatelink host with Terraform?**

Comment: Hi - can you clarify if you have enabled the network policy or not? With the network policy disabled, can you connect Terraform to Snowflake using the privatelink connection? Are you running Terraform within your private network?

Comment: Hi! 
The network policy is not enabled yet and I still cannot connect Terraform to Snowflake with the privatelink. I want to enable the policy with Terraform and can only do it if Terraform is using the privatelink.
Terraform is running in my CI using AzureDevOps which runs my jobs inside VMSS instances that are within my private network.